# Google Chrome packaged app window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a Chrome packaged app that has two pages [for now]. And by pages a mean actual .html files. One is called login.html and the another is index.html.

Now everything related to the user is stored in chrome.storage.local.

Here is the code for launching the pages in chrome.js.

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function () {
    var dimensions = getDimensions(screen),
        positions = getPositions(screen);

    chrome.storage.local.get('login', function (result) {
        if(result.login.status === "loggedOut") {
            chrome.app.window.create('login.html', {
                id: 'loginWindow',
                'bounds': {
                    'width':    400,
                    'height':   600
                },
                minWidth: 400,
                minHeight: 600,
                maxWidth: 400,
                maxHeight: 600,
                frame: 'none'
            });
        } else {
            chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
                id: 'mainWindow',
                'bounds': {
                    'top':      positions.top,
                    'left':     positions.left,
                    'width':    dimensions.width,
                    'height':   dimensions.height
                },
                minWidth: dimensions.width,
                minHeight: dimensions.height,
                maxWidth: dimensions.width,
                maxHeight: dimensions.height,
                frame: 'none'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now because chrome.storage.local.get login.status === loggedOut it pops the login page with the login form. So how do I proceed when the user puts the correct credentials. How do I close the login window and then open the main. The code above is just to open the index.html next time and not showing the login again.

I have done the code to check the credentials and that works, but I want to now close the login form window and open a new index.html with the same bounds, max-, minwidths and heights as you can see in the code above.

Here is what I'm looking for: [this is now in login.js which is called inside login.html]

```
if(login === success) {
    // close login window and goto mainWindow
} else {
    // Username or password is wrong
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do to accomplish this is to add this tho check if changes happen inside the chrome.storage.local.

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('login', function (result) {
        if (result.login.status === "loggedIn") {
            chrome.app.window.get('loginWindow').close();
            chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
                id: 'mainWindow',
                'bounds': {
                    'top':      positions.top,
                    'left':     positions.left,
                    'width':    dimensions.width,
                    'height':   dimensions.height
                },
                minWidth: dimensions.width,
                minHeight: dimensions.height,
                maxWidth: dimensions.width,
                maxHeight: dimensions.height,
                frame: 'none'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Of course you could use those changes and namespaces but I chose to leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

MiroRauhala has answered your direct question, but maybe you should rethink how your app is structured.

Chrome apps don't have navigation like a normal site does. They have windows, and each window corresponds to a different html page. Instead of closing one window and opening a new one up with the exact same bounds, you could just have different divs within the one document which you hide and show as necessary.

I think changing your structure will lead to a simpler app in the long run.

If you do go with the separate window approach you will need to be careful. For example, if you add an id to a window and specify bounds, the bounds are only applied the first time it is shown. Afterwards it remembers the bounds. You can get around that by creating it hidden, then moving it, then showing it. You might run into other things like this as you're using the chrome apps platform in a way it wasn't designed for.

Comment: This window-switch is applied only at login and after user has logged in they can do everything inside that window (other content will be called by ajax). And this is still the pre-pre-alpha-beta-not-stable-release so don't worry, I just wanted to learn more Chrome SDK and play around. I may leave this out in the future. If you have a Spotify installed then you can see just what I'm trying to achieve.